# I am trying to GET from an API in C# and use parts of it to use in the PUT

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I think the answer is obvious but I feel oblivious.    If you have time to point me in the direction I would be thankful.

#### from log ...

> 2023-06-24 00:10:29.270 +00:00 [INF] Response received for /api/MemberDetail/"c4566a7e-fe3d-46e4-abbe-c34d2fc097ce":

```json
{
 "memberId":"c4566a7e-fe3d-46e4-abbe-c34d2fc097ce",
 "imageUrl":"https://dev.xcl.one/Players/a9d17140-2a6b-465d-bcfb-a13770c03eda.jpg",
 "playerName":"FLU",
 "allianceId":"47f2cbcc-91e8-4d3a-ae95-27b2a3782bc1",
 "titleId":"3ccbba59-85fb-491e-92e6-f17f2584776b",
 "rankId":"bdbfe6e6-b515-42d3-b9c8-9dbba42fd06f",
 "honor":0,
 "prestige":100,
 "dateTimeUtc":"2023-06-23T18:35:59.7925881"
}
```

> 2023-06-24 00:10:29.287 +00:00 [INF] Sending PUT request with content:

```json
{
 "memberId":"c4566a7e-fe3d-46e4-abbe-c34d2fc097ce",
 "titleId":"2902c1c0-0fba-4b04-908c-2c2aa7183c82",
 "imageUrl":"",
 "playerName":"",
 "allianceId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
 "rankId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
 "honor":0,
 "prestige":100,
 "dateTimeUtc":"2023-06-24T00:10:29.2785496Z"
}
```

The titleId changes but not the imageUrl, playerName, allianceId, rankId the honor and prestige use the defaults from the model.

```cs
    var getResponse = await client.GetAsync($"/api/MemberDetail/{passedMemberId}");

    //_logger.LogInformation("GET request sent to /api/MemberDetail/{passedMemberId}", passedMemberId);

    if (getResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseContent = await getResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        _logger.LogInformation("Response received for /api/MemberDetail/{passedMemberId}: {responseContent}", passedMemberId, responseContent);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseContent))
        {
            var memberApiDetail = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MemberDetail>(responseContent);

            if (memberApiDetail != null)
            {
                var promotionPayload = new
                {
                    memberId = passedMemberId,
                    titleId = passedTitleId,
                    imageUrl = memberApiDetail.ImageUrl,
                    playerName = memberApiDetail.PlayerName,
                    allianceId = memberApiDetail.AllianceId,
                    rankId = memberApiDetail.RankId,
                    honor = memberApiDetail.Honor != 0 ? memberApiDetail.Honor : 0,
                    prestige = memberApiDetail.Prestige != 100 ? memberApiDetail.Prestige : 100,
                    dateTimeUtc = memberApiDetail.DateTimeUtc
                };

                var promotionPayloadString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(promotionPayload);
                var putContent = new StringContent(promotionPayloadString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                _logger.LogInformation("Sending PUT request with content: {content}", promotionPayloadString);

                var response = await client.PutAsync($"/api/MemberDetail/{passedMemberId}", putContent);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //_logger.LogInformation("Promotion successfully updated for memberId: {memberId}", passedMemberId);
                }
            }
        }
    }
...
    public class MemberDetail
    {
        //public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Key] 
        public Guid MemberId { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string PlayerName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public Guid AllianceId { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
        public Guid TitleId { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
        public Guid RankId { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
        public int Honor { get; set; } = 0;
        public long Prestige { get; set; } = 100;
        public DateTime DateTimeUtc { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
```

Comment: It looks to me like you received the data, but it is not deserializing properly as the values are blank - show us the definition of `MemberDetail` please

Comment: I have added the MemberDetail

Answer (score 0):

I changed the MemberDetail model to add         [JsonPropertyName("memberId")] for all

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).